# Matching a string against an array of strings

Tags: c#

I have an array of four operations which I want to match against an input string.

My attempt:

```
string[] operations = {"add","sub","mul","div"};
string rawInput = Console.ReadLine();
string[] inputs = rawInput.Split(delims,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
firstInput = inputs[0].Trim();

foreach (string operation in operations) 
{
    if (firstInput.Contains(operation))
        Console.WriteLine("Valid operation: {0}",operation);
}
```

As I expected, this prints `Valid operation` if I input add, sub, mul or div.

To print a message for invalid input, I have included an else condition like this:

```
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid operation: {0}", firstInput);
    break;
}
```

If I input `sub` now, I get:

`Invalid operation: sub`

If I remove the break statement and input `sub`:

```
Invalid operation: sub
Valid operation: sub
Invalid operation: sub
Invalid operation: sub
```

How do I modify the logic so that I get correct messages and only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop iterates over each of the entries in `operations`, so your logic is incorrect because it will break out of the loop if the input doesn't match the first element in `operations` (namely, `"add"`).  You really want to break out of the loop if a valid operation is found and otherwise keep scanning.  Here is some sample code:

```
bool validOperation = false;
foreach (string operation in operations) 
{
    if (firstInput.Contains(operation))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid operation: {0}",operation);
        validOperation = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!validOperation)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid operation: {0}", firstInput);
}
```

Comment: Thanks chess007. I like this answer better and really appreciate you for explaining me why the logic was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Look if the first input is in your list of valid operations, instead of the other way around (using LINQ):

```
if (operations.Contains(firstInput))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Valid operation: {0}", firstInput);
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid operation: {0}", firstInput);
}
```

If iterating over the list, as you have done, this is one option:

```
bool foundValidOP = false;
foreach (string operation in operations) 
{
    if (firstInput.Equals(operation, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        foundValidOP = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (foundValidOP)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Valid operation: {0}", firstInput);
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid operation: {0}", firstInput);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oded. I really liked your answer but currently am taking things a little slow and progressing through with basic string operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
string[] operations = { "add", "sub", "mul", "div" };
var firstInput = "sudb";

var x = operations.SingleOrDefault(o => o == firstInput);

if (x != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Valid:" + x);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid:" + firstInput);
```